# Problema en los manejo de archivos .txt

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

Tengo un problema a la hora de leer y escribir de un archivo de texto.
No entiendo el porque no esta funcionado. Cuando compilo el programa todo me funciona bien hasta cuando llega el momento en el que el programa tiene que escribir en el archivo de salidas que me salta el error que le presento en la parte de abajo y no entiendo porque es que pasa eso. le dejo una muestra del código para que vean.

---

### EL código

```
        try {  
            reader = new FileReader(nameOfInputFile + ".txt");
            fileInput = new Scanner(reader);

            while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
                strLine = fileInput.nextLine();
                name = strLine;
                edad = Integer.valueOf(strLine);

                if (edad >= 21) {
                    nameList[matchesCount] = name;
                    matchesCount = matchesCount + 1;

                    edadList[matchesCount] = edad;
                    matchesCount = matchesCount + 1;
                }
            }

            fileInput.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error mensaje los archivos " + e);
        }

        try {

            fileOutput = new PrintWriter(nameOfOutputFile + ".txt");

            for (int j = matchesCount - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

                System.out.println(nameList[j]);
                fileOutput.println(nameList[j]);

                System.out.println(edadList[j]);
                fileOutput.println(edadList[j]);
            }
            fileOutput.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error mensaje los archivos " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

El error que me esta tanto es el siguiente:

### Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Luiz"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at IntroManejoArchivos1.main(IntroManejoArchivos1.java:35)
```

---

### Archivo de texto

```
Luiz
14
Maria
18
Pedro
20
Carlos
41
Juna
8
JunaCarlos
17
```

Comment: ¿Qué formato tiene el archivo? La excepción (que por cierto, aparece en tiempo de ejecución, no de compilación) dice que has leído una línea que pone "Luiz" y que estás intentando ejecutar *Integer.valueOf("Luiz")*, que es lo que hace saltar la excepción (porque obviamente "Luiz" no se puede interpretar como un *int*).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @SJuan76 ahora pude entender mejor el mensaje de error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error está en esta línea:

```
edad = Integer.valueOf(strLine);
```

Pero antes dices que `name = strLine`, por lo que intentas convertir un nombre (en tu caso "Luiz" según el mensaje del error) a entero. No se como están estructuradas las líneas de tu archivo, pero seguramente cada línea contenga más de un dato (nombre, edad, etc) y debes procesarla para extraer la porción correspondiente a cada uno de estos datos.

Si editas tu pregunta y agregas la estructura del archivo y lo que quieres hacer te puedo ayudar más.

**Agregado por edición de la pregunta**

Según la estructura de tu archivo, lo que debes hacer es volver a pedir una nueva línea para capturar la edad. Algo así:

```
while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
    name = fileInput.nextLine();
    edad = -1;

    // Esto lo hago por si no hay más líneas, para que no falle
    if (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
        edad = Integer.valueOf(fileInput.nextLine());
    }

    if (edad >= 21) {
        nameList[matchesCount] = name;
        matchesCount = matchesCount + 1;

        edadList[matchesCount] = edad;
        matchesCount = matchesCount + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, voy ha editar mi pregunta con lo que dice el archivo para que vea como esta escrito.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta y ahora tiene lo que dice el archivo de texto